# Can adding a particular number to a bunch of "time" strings, be done in Regex

Tags: regex, subtitle

I have a "srt" file(like standard movie-subtitle format) like shown in below link:
http://pastebin.com/3k8a53SC

Excerpt:

```
1
00:00:53,000 --> 00:00:57,000
<any text that may span multiple lines>

2
00:01:28,000 --> 00:01:35,000
<any text that may span multiple lines>
```

But right now the subtitles timing is all wrong, as it lags behind by 9 seconds.

Is it possible to add 9 seconds(+9) to every time entry with regex ?
Even if the milliseconds is set to 000 then it's fine, but the addition of 9 seconds should adhere to "60 seconds = 1 minute & 60 minutes = 1 hour" rules.
Also the subtitle text after timing entry must not get altered by regex.

By the way the time format for each time string is "Hours:Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds".

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is "no", that's not an application for regex.  A regular expression lets you MATCH text, but not change it.  Changing things is outside the scope of the regex itself, and falls to the language you're using -- perl, awk, bash, etc.

For the task of adjusting the time within an SRT file, you could do this easily enough in bash, using the `date` command to adjust times.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

offset="${1:-0}"

datematch="^(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}),[0-9]{3} --> (([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}),[0-9]{3}"

os=$(uname -s)

while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ $datematch ]]; then

    # Gather the start and end times from the regex
    start=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    end=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}

    # Replace the time in this line with a printf pattern
    linefmt="${line//[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/%s}\n"

    # Calculate new times
    case "$os" in
      Darwin|*BSD)
        newstart=$(date -v${offset}S -j -f "%H:%M:%S" "$start" '+%H:%M:%S')
        newend=$(date -v${offset}S -j -f "%H:%M:%S" "$end" '+%H:%M:%S')
        ;;
      Linux)
        newstart=$(date -d "$start today ${offset} seconds" '+%H:%M:%S')
        newend=$(date -d "$end today ${offset} seconds" '+%H:%M:%S')
        ;;
    esac

    # And print the result
    printf "$linefmt" "$newstart" "$newend"

  else
    # No adjustments required, print the line verbatim.
    echo "$line"
  fi
done
```

Note the `case` statement.  This script should auto-adjust for Linux, OSX, FreeBSD, etc.

You'd use this script like this:

```
$ ./srtadj -9 < input.srt > output.srt
```

Assuming you named it that, of course.  Or more likely, you'd adapt its logic for use in your own script.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, you can’t. Regex are a context free language (see Chomsky e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) and you cannot calculate.
But with a context sensitive language like perl it will work.
It could be a one liner like this ;-)))

```
perl -n -e 'if(/^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)([-,\d\s\>]*)(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(.*)/) {print plus9($1).$2.plus9($3).$4."\n";}else{print $_}  sub plus9{ ($h,$m,$s)=split(/:/,shift); $t=(($h*60+$m)*60+$s+9); $h=int($t/3600);$r=$t-($h*3600);$m=int($r/60);$s=$r-($m*60);return sprintf "%02d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s;}‘ movie.srt
```

with move.srt like

```
1
00:00:53,000 --> 00:00:57,000
hello

2
00:01:28,000 --> 00:01:35,000
I like perl

3
00:02:09,000 --> 00:02:14,000
and regex
```

you will get

```
1
00:01:02,000 --> 00:01:06,000
hello

2
00:01:37,000 --> 00:01:44,000
I like perl

3
00:02:18,000 --> 00:02:23,000
and regex
```

You can change the +9 in the "sub plus9{...}", if you want another delta.

How does it work?
We are looking for lines that matches
`dd:dd:dd something dd:dd:dd something`
and then we call a sub, which add 9 seconds to the matched group one ($1) and group three ($3). All other lines are printed unchanged.

**added**
If you want to put the perl oneliner in a file, say plus9.pl, you can add newlines ;-)

```
if(/^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)([-,\d\s\>]*)(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(.*)/) {
    print plus9($1).$2.plus9($3).$4."\n";
} else {
    print $_
}

sub plus9{
    ($h,$m,$s)=split(/:/,shift);
    $t=(($h*60+$m)*60+$s+9);
    $h=int($t/3600);
    $r=$t-($h*3600);
    $m=int($r/60);
    $s=$r-($m*60);
    return sprintf "%02d:%02d:%02d", $h, $m, $s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have windows 7 pc, and in cmd when I run your above command it gives message "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect" (perl is installed and in my ENV PATH already). So  can you update this command for windows 7 ?

Comment: Mmmh, what did you get with the command  perl -V  ? Does it work? You should get a version info of perl.

Comment: Yes, as I told you perl is installed and working with ENV PATH set, when I run "perl -v" I get version number which is 5.20.something in my case.

Comment: I've no windows at this moment, maybe tomorrow. I think the "d:" was misinterpreted. Can you use double quotes " instead of the single quote ' around the perl option parameter? But attention, you have to escape the inside double quotes. Alternative you can write it in a file (without the surrounding quotes), say plus9.pl and then call instead perl -n plus9.pl movie.srt

Comment: Thanks, I will try that in windows system.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions strictly do matching and cannot add/substract. You can match each datetime string using python, for example, add 9 seconds to that, and then rewrite the string in the appropriate spot. The regular expression I would use to match it would be the following:

```
(?<hour>\d+):(?<minute>\d+):(?<second>\d+),(?<msecond>\d+)
```

It has labeled capture groups so it's really easy to get each section (you won't need `msecond` but it's there for visualization, I guess)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rJ3dI3/1)